# Oracle - how to find what caused CPU to spike 3 weeks ago

Tags: oracle

On August 22, 2017 at 11:15 on our Oracle 11.2.0.4 (32 cpus, 200GB) we had a cpu spike from 10 to 85% (as seen on AWs cloudwatch).  At 11:25 it went to 100%

Now 3 weeks later we need to understand what sql was running at 11:15 that caused the issue i.e. how much cpu they consumed.  not the ones at 11:25 but ones at 11:15

is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your AWR settings were set up to retention other than default 8 days, for example 30 days, then answer is yes. Or if you have backup of database of that time.

Check settings by script:

SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/awrinfo.sql

At the start of output check for row:
"Snapshot interval is 60 minutes and Retention is **30** days"

If AWR retention is enough and if you have license on Oracle Diagnostic Pack then you can run ashrpt script to see the approximate load on this interval.

SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/ashrpt.sql

Comment: nota bene: AWR needs a separate license (diagnostic pack). As the instance is on AWS, I don't know if you have access to the external sql scripts you need to run AWR or statspack. statspack might work, but won't help in this situation if it wasn't enabled before.